# Spawning Node.js processes as many as CPU cores and load-balancing across them

Tags: node.js, nginx, automation, load-balancing, pm2

I have several machines. For each of them, I'd like to spawn immortal Node.js processes as many as available CPU cores with PM2, and distribute ingress HTTP traffic across them with Nginx, not using PM2's built-in load-balancing feature, namely the "clustering mode."

---

#### For PM2

How do I spawn Node.js processes as many as CPU cores with PM2, without its built-in load-balancing?

#### For Nginx

I could manually specify all the ports to the processes for Nginx, but it's cumbersome to maintain. How do I have it automatically configured as the number of CPU cores changes?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use the nodejs built-in `cluster` module and let it distribute the load?

Comment: @jfriend00 I was told it was less reliable than Nginx's load-balancing. And, using both to load-balance would add up overheads. Nginx can solely do the job, isn't it?

Comment: I feel this might be an XY question.. https://amp.reddit.com/r/node/comments/991kwm/pm2_single_point_of_entry_appjs_or_multiple

Comment: I was considering PM2 for two reasons: 1. it spawns process-per-core with load-balancing, 2. it configures systemd to resurrect them on failure. But now that I know [Nginx is about 5% more performant in load-balancing than Node.js cluster, which PM2 makes use of](https://medium.com/@fermads/node-js-process-load-balancing-comparing-cluster-iptables-and-nginx-6746aaf38272), I’m considering Kubernetes for having process-per-core with Nginx automatically tracking them to distribute loads, ditching PM2. Not sure if I could do this with Kubernetes yet though.